# Oci8Exception in Oci8.php line 466

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, laravel-5.3

Attempting to connect to an Oracle database with yajra/laravel-oci8, below is the configuration. Note that I've also installed the instant client 11g corresponding to the bit version of Windows Server. I've ensured that the 11g ext is enabled in the php.ini.

[image: demo]

Spent 4 days on this now, does anybody have any idea what's going on?

I don't even get an error message, just a stack dump which is attached.

```
'oracle' => [
    'driver'        => 'oracle',
    'tns'           => 'LISTENER',
    'host'          => '192.168.39.73',
    'port'          => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
    'database'      => 'QORA',
    'username'      => 'ETEST',
    'password'      => 'ETEST',
    'charset'       => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
    'prefix'        => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
    'prefix_schema' => env('DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
],
```

Comment: Have you checked the oracle client error log?

Comment: Try a pure OCI8 testcase with error_reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors On.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error messages are showing you are trying to connect on port 3306, which is the standard MySQL port. According to your config, you're looking at the `DB_PORT` value from the `.env` file, with a backup of `1521` if that doesn't exist.

My guess is that your `.env` file has the following line:

```
DB_PORT=3306
```

You either need to comment or remove that line, or change `3306` to `1521`.

Comment: Bloody genius! Thank you!